# Разница между двумя введенными датами в днях

Tags: javascript

```js
 var inputDateOne = document.createElement('input'),
      inputDateTwo = document.createElement('input'),
     inputDateResult = document.createElement('input');
    
    inputDateOne.type = 'data';
    inputDateOne.name = 'valuer';
    
    document.body.appendChild(inputDateOne);
    
    inputDateTwo.type = 'data';
    inputDateTwo.name = 'valuer';
    
    document.body.appendChild(inputDateTwo);
    
    inputDateResult.type = 'data';
    inputDateResult.name = 'valuer';
    
    document.body.appendChild(inputDateResult);
```

Собственно, вот есть инпуты. В первых двух нужно ввести даты, а в третьем получить разницу этих дат в днях. Мне бы хотя бы алгоритм выполнения, а не сам код

Comment: Берете данные из инпутов, переводите в тип `Date`, отнимаете, результат паереводите в дни!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутреннее представление типа `Date` это `Number`. Мы можем получать разницу между датами, просто приводя значения их переменных к числу, и вычисляя разность.

---

Пример:

```js
const DAY_MS = 864e5;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  for (let di of document.querySelectorAll('[type="date"]')) {
    di.valueAsDate = new Date(); 
    di.addEventListener('input', getDiff); 
  }
  let diff = document.getElementById('diff'); 
  diff.addEventListener('input', setDiff); 
  setDiff(diff); 
});

function getDiff() {
  const left  = document.getElementById('left'), 
        right = document.getElementById('right'), 
        diff  = document.getElementById('diff') ; 
  diff.value = Math.abs(Math.round(left.valueAsDate - right.valueAsDate) / DAY_MS); 
}

function setDiff(e) {
  const left  = document.getElementById('left'), 
        right = document.getElementById('right'), 
        diff  = e instanceof Event ? e.target : e; 
  let diffV = parseInt(diff.value) || 0;
  if (Math.abs(diffV) > 999) {
    diff.reportValidity(); 
    return; 
  }
  switch (Math.sign(diffV)) {
    case -1: 
      left.valueAsDate = new Date(+right.valueAsDate + diffV * DAY_MS); 
      break; 
    case 1: 
      right.valueAsDate = new Date(+left.valueAsDate + diffV * DAY_MS); 
      break; 
    default: 
      right.valueAsDate = left.valueAsDate; 
  }
}
```

```css
input, span { font: 18px sans-serif; }
input       { width: 120px; }
.u--shiftnext-30px     { padding-right: 30px; box-sizing: border-box; }
.u--shiftnext-30px + * { margin-left: -30px; pointer-events: none; }
```

```html
<input id="left" type="date" />
<input id="right" type="date" />
◀▶
<input id="diff" class="u--shiftnext-30px" min="-999" max="999" type="number" value="7"/><span>дн.</span>
```

В примере, ввод дат всегда возвращает разницу по модулю.  Ввод разницы: если <0, то меняется левая дата; если >0, то правая.

Comment: Спасибо за привычный минус без указания причины в комменте.

Answer (score 0):

Вычислить разницу м/у датами в миллисекундах: date1.getTime() - date2.getTime(); А затем поделить на кол-во миллисекунд в 24 часах - 86400000.
Я рекомендую использовать momentjs для операций с датами.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ответ причиной: то есть, **почему и зачем** выполнять все эти лишние вычисления и стрелять себе в ногу (високосные года), когда тип инпута `data` автоматически означает HTML5 (а следовательно, и наличие стандартного свойства `valueAsDate`).

Comment: Изменил: убрал всё лишнее.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь суть гораздо яснее. Для автора вопроса добавлю, что вызов `getTime()` при вычитании необязателен (т.к. выполняется автотипкаст к `Number`), но для надежности лучше его все-таки использовать.